# Browsing to home page generates 404 error

Tags: asp.net, iis, iis-7.5

I deployed my ASP.NET application that works within VS Express for Web 2013 to a newly-created server (Windows Server 2008 R2, IIS 7.5).
Browsing to the home page generates a 404 error. Detailed error information:

Module:        IIS Web Core
Notification:  MapRequestHandler
Handler:       StaticFile
 
Error Code:    0x80070002
Requested URL: http://example.com/Account/Login?ReturnUrl=%2Fdefault.aspx
Physical Path: C:\example\Account\Login
Logon Method:  Anonymous
Logon User:    Anonymous

Of course, physical path C:\example\Account\Login does not exist; it is really c:\example\Account\Login.aspx.

My guess would be that the problem is that the handler is StaticFile, but how do I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My initial guess was correct. A hotfix was needed to enable support for extensionless URLs in IIS 7.5. See the Microsoft Knowledge Base article at https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/980368 for details.

Answer (score 0):

Check the request url, it has no .aspx
extension

> Requested URL:
>   http://example.com/Account/**Login**?ReturnUrl=%2Fdefault.aspx

It seems it redirects to the login page, perhaps you have a wrong value in your web.config for your login page, it must be login.aspx, not login

It uses the static file handler, because there is no aspx extension.

**Update**

Put the login.aspx in the root.
Adjust the web.config to look like this:

what you have is

```
<location path="Account/Login">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="*"/>
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
```

it should look like this

```
<system.web>
  <authentication mode="Forms">
    <forms loginUrl="Logon.aspx" name=".ASPXFORMSAUTH">
    </forms>
  </authentication>
<authorization></authorization>
</system.web>
```

Here is a link that might help you:
[Forms Authentication](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xdt4thhy%28v=vs.140%29.aspx)

Comment: Even if I explicitly enter http://example.com/Account/Login.aspx (which you would never do in a real application) I get the exact same error.

Comment: it must be a relative path

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "relative path", and I would like to remind you that my application works just fine on my machine in VS Express for Web.

Comment: Not even to tell me what you mean by "it must be relative path"? Please see web.config at http://pastebin.com/UdTxJPRG.

Comment: if ur login.aspx is in the root u dont have to care about that.
Relatve means relative to the root of your website.

Comment: Your update shows me what is in my web.config, but there is a blank line where I believe your suggestion should be. StackOverflow wants me to move this discussion to Chat, but I don't have enough points to do do. Anyway, I won't be able to try your suggestion (when it is visible) for several hours.

Comment: I am using ASP.Net Identity. The authentication mode is supposed to be "none". By the way, I did not create any of this, other than using the location tag to allow/deny access to certain users/roles. I created a project using the "ASP.NET Web Forms Application" template (or maybe it was another template) and just filled in my code. My existing web.config and everything else works fine on my machine in VS Express (IIS Express 8.x). I believe that my problem is IIS configuration on the new server, but we will see when I try your suggestion to set authentication mode to "Forms".

Comment: The update does not show what is in ur config, take a closer look.